# PHP Solr throws an "Unknown style" error

Tags: php, solr

I have tried looking everywhere for an answer but i can only find references to Unknown Type errors, this seems to be different.

I have installed a nightly snapshot build of solr (apache-solr-4.0-SNAPSHOT.war) which i have had to do because the pdfbox library that comes with stable is too old and would not read them. but that's another story.

What i have at the moment is an error from php SolrClient::AddDocuments() with the error message from the exception as 'Unknown style "html"', please can someone explain what could be causing this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which "stable" are you using?  Solr 3.1 only came out very recently and has quite up to date libraries for content extraction (including pdfbox); I've had much more success with 3.1 than I did with 1.4.1, especially with regards to PDFs.

Comment: I was using the svn checkout version.

Comment: Have you tried using the Solr 3.1 stable version?  It's using pdfbox 1.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a difference in the structures of the config files. I edited the schemea.xml and solr-config.xml files and the error disappeared. Exactly what change made it disappear I am not sure as I amde several at once.

Thats the best answer i have.